# Get the ID from the url in VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am learning VUEJS currently and totally new to this. so i want a help. I want to have the ID from the URL such as:

URL:

```
abc.net/dashboard/a/123456789
```

I want to have the `123456789` in a text format.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can guide you if you're using `vue-router` with options api

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import DashboardComponent from "./path/DashboardComponent";

Vue.use(VueRouter);


export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        
        { path: '/dashboard/a/:id', component: DashboardComponent }//where :id is the dynamic id you wish to access from the browser
    ]
})
```

The in your `DashboardComponent`

```
<template>
   <div> 
       {{id}} //this will show the id in plain text
   </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
       name: 'Dashboard',

       data(){
           return {
              id: this.$route.params.id //this is the id from the browser
           }
       },
    }
</script>
```

**For Vue 3 with compositio API**

```
<script setup> 
    import { defineProps, onMounted } from "vue";
    import { useRouter } from "vue-router";

    const props = defineProps( {
      id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
      }

    onMounted( () => {
        console.log(props.id)
    } )
    
</script>
```

In your *router.js* file,

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter, } from 'vue-router'

const routes = [

    {
       name: "Dashboard", 
       path: "/dashboard/a/:id", 
       component: () => import('./components/../file.vue'), 
       props: true  
     }, 

];

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 5):

This can easily done by plain javascript

```
const url = window.location.href;
const lastParam = url.split("/").slice(-1)[0];
console.log(lastParam);
```

If you are using **vue-router** and the page you load is defined in **router.js**. Then simple call `this.$route.params`